# Datetimepicker displayed wrong after disable then enable

Tags: vb.net, datetimepicker

I have a checkbox. On checkbox_CheckedChanged I set datetimepicker.Enabled like this:

```
Private Sub checkbox_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles checkbox.CheckedChanged
    If Me.checkbox.Checked Then
        Me.txt1.Enabled = True
        Me.dtp1.Enabled = True
    Else
        Me.txt1.Enabled = False
        Me.dtp1.Enabled = False
    End If
End Sub
```

At fisrt, dtp1 look like this:

[image: dtp1]

When checkbox checked = False, dtp1 look like this:

[image: dtp1 disabled]

When checkbox checked = True, dtp1 look like this:

[image: dtp1 enabled]

And after enabled again, when tabstop on dtp1 is not hightlight anymore and the border color displayed wrong.

Can anyone explain that? I want the dtp1 look like at first when enabled again. Can any one tell me how to do that?

Comment: Do you have the `TextBox` positioned in front of the `DateTimePicker`?

Comment: Yes, I have. It's a part of DateTimePicker

Comment: Um, no. A `DateTimePicker` is a `DateTimePicker` and a `TextBox` is a `TextBox`. Have you done something other than simply add both controls to the form and put one over the other? If so, maybe you could explain that as there's a distinct possibility that what you have done is the reason for the behaviour you're seeing.

Comment: I just check that again, there is a TextBox positioned in front of the DateTimePicker

Comment: In some case value need to set to null, and the DateTimePicker can not do that show I have to use text box instead

Comment: The usual method is to set the `ShowCheckBox` property to `True` and then let the `Checked` property indicate whether a value is considered present or not. If you did want to stick with the two controls, I'd probably recommend incorporating them into a single user control and then adding that to your form. That way, all the complexity is encapsulated in the control and your form code is simple.